# SQL Server 2016 JSON_VALUE syntax

Tags: sql-server, json, sql-server-2016

I have an API returning data in the form:

```
  "cars" : {"VW":{"name":"Volkswagen","country":"Germany"}, 
            "GM":{"name":"General Motors","country":"USA"},
            "RR":{"name":"Rolls Royce","country":"UK"}
            }
```

Using `JSON_VALUE`, how do I reference the two character designator "VW","GM", etc.?
I can get the name & country by using the path `$.cars` but can't see how to get the (unnamed) field. The API isn't mine so I cannot dictate the format.

Answer (score 2):

What will this query return?

```
set @json = N'  
["cars" : {
    "VW":{
        "name":"Volkswagen",
        "country":"Germany"}, 
    "GM":{
        "name":"General Motors",
        "country":"USA"},
    "RR":{
        "name":"Rolls Royce",
        "country":"UK"}
}]';

select *   
from OPENJSON( @json )
```

Could you please share the output?

I apologize for given this as an answer, but is too long for comment and this query might help to find the elements that OP want to obtain.

**EDIT#1**

This:

```
Declare @js nvarchar(4000) = N'{"cars" : {
            "VW":{"name":"Volkswagen","country":"Germany"}, 
            "GM":{"name":"General Motors","country":"USA"},
            "RR":{"name":"Rolls Royce","country":"UK"}}}'

SELECT [key]
FROM OPENJSON (@js,'$.cars')
```

Will give you values you need.

**EDIT#2**

And you can reference on this values:

```
SELECT p1.[key],
       p2.[key],
       p2.[value]
FROM OPENJSON (@js, '$.cars') as p1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON ([value], '$')
) p2
WHERE p1.[key] = 'VW'
```

Output:

```
key key     value      
--- ------- ---------- 
VW  name    Volkswagen 
VW  country Germany    

(2 row(s) returned)
```

Comment: It would appear this is almost correct. `select [key] from openjson(json_query(@js, '$.cars'))` does it.

Comment: @GSerg Thanks for checking! I don't have SQL Server 2016 installed on my PC so cannot check. But I remember that `OPENJSON` should return parsed data from json variable.

Comment: I don't have it either. Martin Smith [posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543633/sql-server-2016-json-value-syntax/39548190?noredirect=1#comment66405464_39545533) a link to a saved query in the stackexchange data fiddler that uses SQL Server 2016. Click Fork and have a go.

Comment: @GSerg why I haven't use this stuff earlier? Because I didn't know about it! Thank you, once again! I have seen the link from Martin, but thought it was a link to another question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i don't have access to SQL Server 2016 to verify it on my own right now. But [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/01/06/json-in-sql-server-2016-part-2-of-4/) should help you.

- '$' – references entire JSON object in the input text
- '$.property1' – references property1 in JSON object
- '$[4]' – references 5-th element in JSON array (indexes are counted from 0 like in JavaScript)
- '$.property1.property2.array1[5].property3.array2[15].property4' – references complex nested property in the JSON object
- '$.info. "first name"' – references "first name" property in info object. If key contains some special characters such as space, dollar, etc., it should be surrounded with double quotes

Comment: How does this help to answer the question?

Comment: SEDE is on SQL Server 2016 so you can access it here https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/540682

Comment: @MartinSmith I believe the OP wants to get the list of keys ("VM", "GM", "RR").

Comment: @GSerg I believe that too but didn't know how to do that. Just left a demo query that can be forked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.
I already thought I knew the answer, except that I was writing it as p1.key and getting an error in SSMS, which threw me off course.  It wasn't until I read your solutions that I realised I had to write it as p1.[key] because *key* is a reserved word.  Rather silly to call the columns 'key' and 'value', I think, when the first is a reserved word in MS SQL and the second is a reserved word in ISO SQL.  Live and Learn.